# Simple Java regex not working

Tags: java, regex, string, operators, operator-precedence

I have this regex which is supposed to remove sentence delimiters(`.` and `?`):

```
sentence = sentence.replaceAll("\\.|\\?$","");
```

It works fine it converts

`"I am Java developer."` to `"I am Java developer"`

`"Am I a Java developer?"` to `"Am I a Java developer"`

But after deployment we found that it also replaces any other dots in the sentence as

`"Hi.Am I a Java developer?"` becomes `"HiAm I a Java developer"`

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The [**pipe**](http://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) (`|`) has the lowest precedence of all operators. So your regex:

```
\\.|\\?$
```

is being treated as:

```
(\\.)|(\\?$)
```

which matches a `.` **anywhere** in the string and matches a `?` at the **end** of the string.

To fix this you need to group the `.` and `?` together as:

```
(?:\\.|\\?)$
```

You could also use:

```
[.?]$
```

Within a character class `.` and `?` are treated literally so you need not escape them.

Comment: When you thank someone, check his answer as useful, that's a minimum ;-). +1 for the detailed explanation

Answer (score 8):

What you're saying with `"\\.|\\?$"` is "either a period" *or* "a question mark as the last character".

I would recommend `"[.?]$"` instead in order to avoid the confusing escaping (and undesirable result, of course).

Comment: Not the only one with this idea, it seems :)

Comment: +1 to align scores with Mark Byers since they are same answers :p

Answer (score 7):

Your problem is because of the low [precedence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_of_operations) of the [alternation operator](http://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) `|`.  Your regular expression means match one of:

- `.` anywhere *or*
- `?` at the end of a line.

Use a character class instead:

```
"[.?]$"
```

Answer (score 3):

You have forgotten to embrace the sentence-ending characters with round brackets:

```
sentence = sentence.replaceAll("(\\.|\\?)$","");
```

The better approach is to use `[.?]$` like @Mark Byers suggested.

```
sentence = sentence.replaceAll("[.?]$","");
```