# Regular expression pipe confusion

Tags: regex

How come this code returns true?

string to match: `ab`

pattern:  `/^a|b$/`

but when I put parentheses like this:

pattern:  `/^(a|b)$/`

it will then return `false`.

Comment: PHP, C++, Python, which regex implementation are you asking about? (Looks like PHP PCRE to me.)

Comment: I believe they have the same implementation regarding the code I've provided so I've put them on the tags :/

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The first pattern without the parenthesis is equivalent to `/(^a)|(b$)/`.
The reason is, that the pipe operator ("alternation operator") has the lowest precedence of all regex operators: http://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html (Third paragraph below the first heading)

Answer (score 10):

`/^a|b$/` matches a string which begins with an `a` OR ends with a `b`. So it matches `afoo`, `barb`, `a`, `b`.

`/^(a|b)$/` : Matches a string which begins and ends with an `a` or `b`. So it matches either an `a` or `b` and nothing else.

This happens because alteration `|` has very low precedence among regex operators.

[Related discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4041266/simple-java-regex-not-working/4041279#4041279)

Answer (score 4):

The first means begin by an `a` or end with a `b`.

The second means 1 character, an `a` or a `b`.

Answer (score 2):

`|` has lower priority than the anchors, so you're saying either `^a` or `b$` (which is true) as opposed to the 2nd one which means "a single character string, either `a` or `b`" (which is false).

Comment: it has a **lower** priority, not a higher one!

Comment: Er, sure, I meant it's evaluated *before* :) I've always found this lower/higher thing arbitrary and counter-intuitive...

Comment: But it's not evaluated _before_ -- it's evaluated _after_. Lowest priority is evaluated last, highest is first. That should be intuitive. I think it's the "before/after" terminology that's causing the confusion, since outermost/biggest actually suggests lower priority.

Answer (score 2):

In `^a|b$` you are matching for an `a` at the beginning or a `b` at the end.

In `^(a|b)$` you are matching for an `a` or a `b` being the only character (at beginning and end).